# Can a proctored online COVID antigen test be used to travel to the Netherlands?

Tags: usa, covid-19, netherlands

Given that the negative test result report provides [the required information](https://www.government.nl/topics/coronavirus-covid-19/visiting-the-netherlands-from-abroad/mandatory-negative-test-results-and-declaration/information-on-the-test-result) and the test is taken less than 24 hours before departure, can a telehealth COVID test be used to enter the Netherlands from the United States? As examples, the BinaxNOW and Ellume tests offer this service.

Comment: Just for clarity, many BinaxNOW tests in the US are not proctored. You just buy the test at the drug store or online and take it yourself, but there's no way to have it proctored and have an official report generated. Other BinaxNOW tests, like the [ones sold through eMed](https://www.emed.com/products/covid-at-home-testkit-six-pack), include proctoring and an app that reports results.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used the particular providers you mentioned, but instead used Vault Health, which offers the same type of service (both at-home with video proctoring, and in-person at certain sites).

Their test result PDF file does present lots of details about the lab methods used for testing, and the authorization from the FDA under which the test is provided, but there is no indication whatsoever on the circumstances under which the test was provided. So presumably nobody would know that it was taken at home anyway.
You could just take a test with the provider you intend to use, and see what their results documentation looks like.